# Using set and line.split python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('dict.txt') as f:
    dict = set(line.rstrip() for line in f)

with open('pag.txt') as pag, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in pag:
        if line.split(',', 2)[1] in dict:
            output.write(line)
```

Dict.txt

```
509344
827276
324194
782211
772854
727246
858908
280903
377881
247333
538710
182734
701212
379326
148310
542129
315285
840427
581092
485581
867746
(...)


1,324194,20190103,0000048632,00000000000004870,0000045054
1,701212,20190103,0000048632,00000000000147072,0000045055
1,581092,20190103,0000048632,00000000000032900,0000045056
(...)
```

If I use this code with a small file, it works fine, and I get the lines. But If I use this code with a very big file, I´m getting this error:

IndexError: list index out of range

Anyway to fix it? I´m kind new at python

Comment: Try printing line.split(',', 2) and check what is the last print before the error. You might have some different data where it cant split it into 3 parts. Since you are using the index 2 [2] you need a list of at least 3 items, if not it will fail.

Comment: The error is clear in itself: you are trying to access an element that does not exist within the scope of the list.

Comment: I´m printing line.split(',', 2) . Thanks for understand the error.

Comment: There's a line without comma and `split()` returns only one element instead of two. You should handle that case.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I found the problem and fix it =)